# I don't understand what is wrong

Tags: kotlin

I am new in kotlin and i don't understand what is wrong, when i do a "CLICK" in the imageView (val_jugadorX.alpha = 0.5f) i can't unselect it again (val_jugadorX.alpha = 1f)

```
fun comprobarSeleccion(val_jugadorX: ImageView): Boolean{
            // si el boleano es false, no está seleccionado
            // si el boleano es verdadero, está seleccionado
            var devolver: Boolean = false

            if (val_jugadorX.alpha == 1f){
                val_jugadorX.setOnClickListener {
                    val_jugadorX.alpha = 0.5f
                    println("Ahora está seleccionado")
                    devolver = true
                }
            }else if(val_jugadorX.alpha== 0.5f) {
                val_jugadorX.setOnClickListener{
                    val_jugadorX.alpha = 1f
                    println("Ahora no está selccio")
                    devolver = false
                }
            }
            return devolver
        }
```

Comment: It might help to add a tag indicating what platform this is for. (Both Android and JavaFX have an ImageView class.) Also: is this function called just once, when setting up the UI, or does it get called at other times too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting a click listener based on the `ImageView`'s *current* alpha, and that click listener *changes* the alpha. But it doesn't call `comprobarSeleccion` *again* to set a new click listener based on its *new* alpha. You probably want to do something like this:

```
fun comprobarSeleccion(val_jugadorX: ImageView): Boolean{
            // si el boleano es false, no está seleccionado
            // si el boleano es verdadero, está seleccionado
            var devolver: Boolean = false

            if (val_jugadorX.alpha == 1f){
                val_jugadorX.setOnClickListener {
                    val_jugadorX.alpha = 0.5f
                    println("Ahora está seleccionado")
                    devolver = true
                    // now the alpha has changed, we need a new click listener
                    comprobarSeleccion(val_jugadorX)
                }
            } ...
        }
```

Although something like this might be better (maybe set up during initialisation):

```
someImageView.setOnClickListener {
    with(someImageView) {
        val selected = alpha == 1f
        // update display
        alpha = if (selected) 0.5f else 1f
        // handle the selection change event
        setSelected(selected)
    }
}
```

That way you just set a click listener once, and it handles things depending on its current state. By having a separate `setSelected` function, you can tell another part of the app that this selection state has changed:

```
var devolver = false

fun setSelected(selected: Boolean) {
    println(if (selected) "Ahora está seleccionado" else "Ahora no está selccio")
    devolver = selected
    // any other stuff that needs to happen because of the selection change
}
```

That fixes your other problem - in your example, `devolver` is a *local* variable inside `comprobarSeleccion`. You set it to *false*, then return it (i.e. return *false*). If a click listener changes it later, nothing can access it. Next time you call `comprobarSeleccion` you get a *new* `devolver` set to *false* again.

By making it a top-level variable, your `setSelected` function can change it (or your click listener can if you want) and everything else can see its current value.